# Way to reduce execution time of this query in mysql

Tags: mysql

Some time ago I needed a little help here to build a custom query. And this query worked fine till now.
 
When I run the query (in a procedure) I get the error:

```
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

My access to my.ini via ssh is read only (because my db is in a shared host "godaddy") so I can't increase the execution time (actual is 60)

Is there one way to optimize this query to make it more fast?

The query is:

```
SELECT @curRank := @curRank + 1 as rank, p.nick,(kills + ((p.vpos - p.vneg)*5) + (top * 5) - deaths) as score
FROM (SELECT 
 (SELECT uuid FROM players WHERE players.uuid = p.uuid LIMIT 1) as uuid,
 (SELECT nick FROM nicks n WHERE n.pid = p.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as nick,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kills k WHERE k.pid = p.id ) as kills,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deaths d WHERE d.pid = p.id ) as deaths,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM headshots h WHERE h.pid = p.id ) as hs,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votos vp WHERE vp.vid = p.id AND tipo="p") as vpos,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votos vn WHERE vn.vid = p.id AND tipo="n") as vneg,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM top_rounds t WHERE t.pid = p.id ) as top,
 (SELECT @curRank := 0) as rank
FROM players p
) p ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 30;
```

Note: all pid's and p.id's already are indexes

Comment: Hi @DrewPierce! Can you help me to make it better? Thanks in advance! Actual 2k+ players, at once exactly 32 players

Comment: You could post the table schemas and some sample data. The main thing I can see is you're doing far too many SELECTs within the SELECT itself, which would be much better if you could accomplish the same thing using JOINS. I can honestly say I've never written a `SELECT from (SELECT FROM (SELECT ..., SELECT ... SELECT ... SELECT ... AS Something) in 25+ years of writing code and SQL. We could probably help to make it more efficient, but how to do so is impossible to say, because you've given us no table definitions or data from the tables to use to attempt to help.

Comment: an alternative approach is to run this query and get baseline numbers globally for all players assuming it works at some point in time without the timeout. let's call that time T1 with N # of total games and jammed into a Global Stats Table. Then at the end of each game or so @ time T2, a more measly subset of data is run against which would be bearable, and those numbers are additive to the Global Stats Table.

Comment: @KenWhite that is a freak query.. sorry mysql is not my area. #Drew Pierce.. Thanks for your help to!

Comment: You've been asked (more than once) to [edit] to provide table schemas and sample data. If you won't give us info to help you, it's much more difficult (whether it's your *area* or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested (due to lack of sample data):

```
SELECT p.nick,
       (IFNULL(k.cnt, 0)
        + ((IFNULL(vpos.cnt, 0) - IFNULL(vneg.cnt, 0))*5)
        + (IFNULL(t.cnt, 0) * 5) - IFNULL(d.cnt, 0) AS score
FROM players p
     LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT pid, COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM kills
       GROUP BY pid
     ) AS k ON p.id = k.pid
     ⋮
     LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT pid, COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM top_rounds
       GROUP BY pid
     ) AS t ON p.id = t.pid
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 30
```

i.e. make sure each inner query runs once only for all the players. Each subquery results in a table which maps player id to corresponding count. Since there might be zero matching rows, we have to use `LEFT JOIN` and translate `NULL` into `0` using `IFNULL(foo.cnt, 0)`.

If you need to index rows, you can add an extra outer query for that alone, but personally I'd prefer to handle that outside SQL in the application which processes the query result.

Comment: Hi @MvG.. Awesome!!! with this the query was executed with just 1.85sec.. But nick is in nicks table.. and de last register is the newer nick for that pid.. And how can i retrieve this last record of nick? I tried http://pastebin.com/UUg9wK62 but aways i get the same nick.. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Fixed now.. my mistake was in a group by in vneg and vpos @MvG Thanks Again!